# How do I refactor nested as_json in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I often get json with code like

```
@user.blogs.includes(comments: :upvotes).as_json(include: { comments: { include: :upvotes } })
```

but it's not very DRY since I'm practically writing the same thing twice. Is there a way to automatically serialize the eager-loaded data?

Comment: Use ActiveModel::Serializers, jbuilder or any of the JSONAPI serializers instead of `as_json`.